# Oppo A15 mobile phone not detected memory card

Tags: external-sd, ram

I've an oppo A15 mobile phone. I purchased a new Toshiba 16gb micro sdhc flash memory card.BUT PHONE'S NOT DETECTED MEMORY CARD AT ALL?
I tried all file browser's but it seems obvious that it's actually going to need to be registered/somehow?

Comment: how did you format

Comment: I have tried file apps and Toshiba sites which seems to be SanDisk. I've a Toshiba flash memory microSD card SDHC 16GB WHICH I JUST CAN'T GET MY OPPO a15 -CPH2185AU_11_A.27- to detect at all, it's been days.

Comment: I didn't? Help would be great!

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info